# ajax function not work on ie10

Tags: ajax

i use this code for get each teacher lesson list this code work fine in all browser but in ie10 cant get lesson list and return blank selection list .

```
 function get_lesson(lesson)
    {
    var getid=lesson;
    document.getElementById("ajax_msg").innerHTML='<span style="color:red">Update</span>';
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

        document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("ajax_msg").innerHTML='Now Select';

        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","subpage/ajax_lesson.php?id=" + getid + "&tnow="+ (new Date()).getTime(),true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

Comment: User jquery ajax function                              

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

IE 10 seems having issue with ajax.
Please Refer:

http://code.gishan.net/code/solution-to-ie10-ajax-problem/

HTH,